# How to retrieve real date when passed through CONVERT() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
  i.owneridname,
  CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(DD,-15,createdon),101) as createdon,
  COUNT(i.svb_contactname) AS [Yes], /* This is a conditional. It only shows non-null values*/
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(i.svb_contactname) AS [No] /* COUNT(*) counts null and non-null, hence why the subtraction here works*/
FROM incident i
WHERE i.svb_caseinitiatedfrom IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '16', '17')
  AND i.svb_status_case IN ('1', '2', '12')
GROUP BY
  i.owneridname, createdon
ORDER BY
  [Yes] DESC;
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDPJt.jpg)

The image shows the results (minus the owneridname column) with values passed from the CONVERT function. I was using the DATEADD function to only pull dates up to 15 days previously, yet it's passing all dates in what seems like a text format and not as a 'real' date.

I tried another WHERE clause but it didn't seem to work.

```
WHERE i.svb_caseinitiatedfrom IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '16', '17')
  AND i.svb_status_case IN ('1', '2', '12')
  AND createdon >= DATEADD(DD,-15,createdon)
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Also, **never** use a `varchar` without a size `CONVERT(varchar` - you need to specify the size, always - else you will be tripped up when it truncates your value.

Comment: `createdon >= DATEADD(DD,-15,createdon)`? Huh? When is a date not on or after the date 15 days prior to it..?

Comment: And you are really confusing yourself by aliasing the new column with the old column name, because everywhere else in your query its using the original column value, not the converted value

Comment: You probably just want `createdon >= DATEADD(DD,-15,getdate())`

Comment: @DaleK By default the server returns a '2016-03-29 21:48:31.000' format and I am trying to convert it down to a simple mm/dd/yyy format, and then to group the dates from there.

Comment: @DaleK it would always be true. It is saying the createdon >= 15 days ago.

Comment: The 'createdon >= DATEADD(DD,-15,createdon)' was an error I realized after I posted the question - was trying to edit/delete the post but doesn't seem I can do that.

Comment: If you want to group your dates by day then you want to group them by a date datatype, not a string representation.

Comment: Something like "Where convert(date, createdon) >= dateadd(day, 15, getdate())"

Comment: @SeanLange precisely what I was trying to accomplish - how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @hobosapien instead of converting it to a string, convert it to a date - since thats what it is.

Comment: But my comment above stands, in your group by, its using the original unchanged column value, just because you alias your new column to be the same as the old, its not used in the group by. You would be better of using `convert(date,createdon)` in the group by directly.

Comment: And you can definitely edit you question there is a link below it, or [edit]

Comment: Further note, the server doesn't return the format you mention, dates and datetimes are stored in an internal binary format. Thats just the SSMS default datetime format.

Comment: @DaleK `convert(date, createdon) >= dateadd(day, -15, getdate())` works to filter the results to the last 15 days, but how do I then group them by those dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be laboring under the impression that `GROUP BY` expressions will refer to the columns in the `SELECT`. This is not the case. `GROUP BY` is logically before the `SELECT` (even though it is placed afterwards in the query), so it is actually referring to the underlying column value. If you had given them two different names then the problem would have been obvious.

To get the date without a time, it's better to just `CAST` to `date`. In SQL Server 2022 and Azure SQL, use `DATETRUNC(day, i.createdon)` instead of `CAST`, as this works better with indexes.

It also seems you want some date logic in the `WHERE`. Don't do functions on the columns in the `WHERE`, only do the functions on the value you want to compare it to (in this case `GETDATE`).

```sql
SELECT
  i.owneridname,
  CAST(i.createdon AS date) as createdon,
  COUNT(i.svb_contactname) AS [Yes], /* This is a conditional. It only shows non-null values*/
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(i.svb_contactname) AS [No] /* COUNT(*) counts null and non-null, hence why the subtraction here works*/
FROM incident i
WHERE i.svb_caseinitiatedfrom IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '16', '17')
  AND i.svb_status_case IN ('1', '2', '12')
-- take current date/time, cast to date to truncate the time to midnight, subtract 15 days
  AND i.createdon >= DATEADD(day, -15, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime))
GROUP BY
  i.owneridname,
  CAST(i.createdon AS date)
ORDER BY
  [Yes] DESC;
```

Comment: When I attempted your code the server gave me an error saying it didn't recognize the word 'GROUP'. So I slightly changed the code to `AND i.createdon >= DATEADD(day, -15, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))` and it provides results, however it is not grouping by the date and only grouping by name.